# How to convert string to C-style string

Tags: c++

I want to read a config file using C++

My code is here:

#### myutils.h

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void read_login_data(char *login_data,map<string,string> &data_map);
```

#### myutils.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "myutils.h"

using namespace std;

void read_login_data(char *login_data,map<string,string> &data_map)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string config_line;
    infile.open(login_data);
    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "can not open login_data";
        return false;

    }
    stringstream sem;
    sem << infile.rdbuf();
    while(true)
    {
        sem >> config_line;
        while(config_line)
        {
            size_t pos = config_line.find('=');
            if(pos == npos) continue;
            string key = config_line.substr(0,pos);
            string value = config_line.substr(pos+1);
            data_map[key]=value;

        }
    }


}
```

#### test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "myutils.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char login[] = "login.ini";
    map <string,string> data_map;

    read_login_data(login,data_map);
    cout<< data_map["BROKER_ID"]<<endl;
    char FRONT_ADDR[20]=data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str();
    cout << FRONT_ADDR<<endl;
}
```

The config file is:

```
BROKER_ID=66666
INVESTOR_ID=00017001033
```

When I compile it using `g++ -o test test.cpp`, the output is:

```
young001@server6:~/ctp/ctp_github/trader/src$ g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp   
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
test.cpp:23:50: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

how can I assign the `data_map["BROKER_ID"]` to `FRONT_ADDR`?

I have used

```
strncpy(FRONT_ADDR, data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str(), sizeof(FRONT_ADDR));
```

But when I compile it, it says:

```
young001@server6:~/ctp/ctp_github/trader/src$ g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp   
/tmp/cc5iIQ6k.o: In function `main':  
test.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `read_login_data(char*, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >&)'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: data_map["BROKER_ID"] is a string,so the data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str() is a c_style string,but it can't direct assign to FRONT_ADDR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char FRONT_ADDR[20]=data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str();
```

You can't do this. You should use `strncpy`(or `copy_n`, but in this case you should check, that length of `data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str()` is greater or equal to `n`) to copy one array of char into another.

```
std::strncpy(FRONT_ADDR, data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str(), sizeof(FRONT_ADDR));
```

And, the best choose, of course, using `std::string`:

```
std::string FRONT_ADDR = data_map["BROKER_ID"];
// and, anywhere you need const char*
somefunction(FRONT_ADDR.c_str());
```

Comment: when I use strncpy,a new problem comes,I have update my question.

Comment: You have to compile `myutils.cpp` too, and then link it. Or just `g++ -Wall -o test myutils.cpp test.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
char FRONT_ADDR[20]={0}; //all elements 0
std::strcpy(FRONT_ADDR, data_map["BROKER_ID"].c_str()); // assuming there is enough space in FRONT_ADDR
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is an inbuilt method(`c_str()`) to do the conversion.
Here's an example.

```
char* cs[10];
Qstring s("string");
cs = s.c_str();
```